# How do you construct a series in which the difference between the cumulative sum and the last term is a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I'm working on gambling strategy. I need to control the risk of gambling, and I want that if $n-1$ consecutive bets win and the nth loses, the cumulative loss should be a constant.
Assuming that the odds of this gamble are $1:1$, each bet is an item in a series, so.
I wish to find a positive integer series $$a{1},a{2},a{3},.... ,a{n}$$ assuming the sum of the first $n$ terms is $S(n)$, and requiring $S(n-1)-an$ to be a constant:
$$C = S(n-1)-an$$

I have now found only one series that meets the conditions:

An isoperimetric series whose common ratio is $q$ and first term is $1$:
$$1,q,q^2,q^3,... ,q^n$$
The cumulative loss until the lose at nth time should be.
$$\frac{2q^{n-1}-q^n-1}{q-1}$$
Obviously,$ q = 2$ is met, and $C=-1$(1 unit of money will be lost after the last loss).

The condition is not satisfied when the series is an equal-difference series. This is because for an equivariate series with tolerance $d$, the cumulative money lost after the nth loss is.
$$\frac{d(n-2)(n-1)}{2} - d(n-1)+n-2$$
This is a quadratic function and the result cannot be a constant.

Is there any other way to construct such a series?

Comment: I have never seen the term “isoperimetric” used in this way, and the sequences in question are generally referred to as *geometric* sequences.  Similarly, a sequence with a constant adjacent difference is an *arithmetic* sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $n \ge 1$,
$$
S_{n - 1} - a_n = S_n - a_{n + 1} = C.
$$
Noting that $S_n = S_{n - 1} + a_n$, rearrangement gives
$$
a_{n + 1} = 2 a_n.
$$
Boundary conditions show that $a_1 = -C$, so the only sequence satisfying the given conditions is
$$
a_n = -C \cdot 2^{n - 1}. 
$$